# Keyboard Shortcut for Filling in Parameters in SSMS Stored Procedure

Tags: ssms

Does anyone know the keyboard shortcut that calls the SSMS tool window for filling in the parameters of a stored procedure template?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Its called Specify Values for Template Parameters and has a shortcut of Ctrl-Shift-M.